# error: no match for call to '(Address) (const char [6], const char [6], const char [6], const char [6])'

Tags: c++

He hecho un archivo de cabecera para declara mi constructor, luego lo definí en este archivo address.cpp y lo comencé a probar en mi declarando varios objetos p, p0 y p1. Y es en p1 donde ocurre el error porque meti los string como parámetros por valor.

Mi pregunta es como evito este error, o si me falto declarar otro constructor para que resiba parámetros y como se hace.

```
// File: address.cpp

#include "address.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
// Put your method bodies for the address class here

//display
void Address :: display() const
{
    cout << getStreet() << endl;
    cout << getCity() << ", " << getState() << " " << getZip() << endl;
}

//Constructor
Address :: Address()
{
    street = "unknown";
    city = "";
    state = "";
    zip = "00000";
}

Address :: Address(string nStreet, string nCity, string nState, string nZip)
{
    setStreet(nStreet);
    setCity(nCity);
    setState(nState);
    setZip(nZip);
}
//~Address();

//set
void Address :: setStreet(string nStreet)
{
    this -> street = nStreet;
}

void Address :: setCity(string nCity)
{
    this -> city = nCity;
}

void Address :: setState(string nState)
{
    this -> state = nState;
}

void Address :: setZip(string nZip)
{
    this -> zip = nZip;
}

int main()
{
    Address p;
    p.display();

    string loco1 = "loco1";
    string loco2 = "loco2";
    string loco3 = "loco3";
    string loco4 = "loco4";

    Address p0(loco1,loco2,loco3,loco4);
    p0.display();

    Address p1;
    p1("loco1", "loco2", "loco3", "loco4" ); //es aquí donde ocurre el error
    //cuando compilo me sale esto:
    //address.cpp:69:41: error: no match for call to '(Address) (const char [6], const char [6], const char [6], const char [6])'

    p1.display();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estás usando el constructor de `Adress` sobre `p1` pero el objeto ya está construido, en lugar de esto:

```
Address p1;
p1("loco1", "loco2", "loco3", "loco4" );
```

Querías hacer esto:

```
Address p1("loco1", "loco2", "loco3", "loco4" );
```